# Single goroutine read and write a map with different channels in a select is thread safe?

Tags: go, data-structures, thread-safety, goroutine

I'm trying to implement a session manager for my web app. It consists in a single goroutine that manages the sessions in an in-memory map to avoid requests to the database. I did not implemented the full version yet, before I would like to know why is this approach thread safe.

The implementation looks as follows:

```
type Session struct {
    Id        uuid.UUID `json:"sessionId"`
    Email     string    `json:"email"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"createdAt"`
}

type SessionManager struct {
    loadBulk  chan uint8 // buffered channel
    load      chan Session
    get       chan uuid.UUID
    resultGet chan Session
    remove    chan uuid.UUID
}

func (sm SessionManager) LoadBulk() {
    sm.loadBulk <- 1
}

func (sm SessionManager) Load(s Session) {
    sm.load <- s
}

func (sm SessionManager) Get(id uuid.UUID) Session {
    sm.get <- id
    return <-sm.resultGet
}

func (sm SessionManager) Remove(id uuid.UUID) {
    sm.remove <- id
}

func NewSessionManager() *SessionManager {
    sessionManager := SessionManager{
        loadBulk:  make(chan uint8, 1),
        load:      make(chan Session),
        get:       make(chan uuid.UUID),
        resultGet: make(chan Session),
        remove:    make(chan uuid.UUID),
    }

    sessions := make(map[uuid.UUID]Session) // this map will be read/write

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-sessionManager.loadBulk:
                log.Info().Msg("Load session bulk get all non expired from database")
            case session := <-sessionManager.load:
                log.Info().Msg("Load session " + fmt.Sprintf("%v", session.Id))
            case id := <-sessionManager.get:
                log.Info().Msg("Get session " + fmt.Sprintf("%v", id))
                sessionManager.resultGet <- Session{}
            case id := <-sessionManager.remove:
                log.Info().Msg("Remove session " + fmt.Sprintf("%v", id))
            case <-time.After(30 * time.Second):
                log.Info().Msg("Remove expired sessions from map and database")
            }
        }
    }()

    return &sessionManager
}
```

There will be only one instance of `SessionManager`. If multiple requests comes to my server and I use the `SessionManager` methods to read/write the map at the same time, could I have thread safety problems? why?

Comment: This is thread-safe as far as the Go runtime is concerned, but there is no guarantee that what you receive from sm.resultGet correlates to what you sent to sm.get. In other words, Get may return a different session than what it was asked for. Is there a particular reason to not use a simple (RW)Mutex?

Comment: You also don't know in the caller when the load or delete request has completed, so you may be working with an unexpected state

Comment: thanks guys for answering. @Peter I'm not using a mutex because I was thinking that with another channel was enough, in the `get` channel branch how can I return a value (maybe I should put the map as a field of SessionManager and use a read mutex)? @Erwin in your case, what should I use instead? Maybe a response back in the same channel when finish?

Comment: In the request channels you could pass a struct with two fields - the parameter and the return channel. For the functions without a return value you could simply close the channel - in both cases you crest a return channel for each request and wait to receive a value on it

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I will avoid the problem of returning different sessions that Peter said? Could you provide a minimal example to show how to do it?

Comment: You are trying to use a goroutine+channels to simulate a simple mutex. This works, but is a lot more complicated, just create a type which can allow safe concurrent access and it will make the code a lot more clear.

Comment: This is how you can make Get work: https://go.dev/play/p/vJMGMRolNCS. As you can see, it's far more complicated than using a Mutex.